# How to integrate django rest-framework and angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

This might be simple answer, but I cannot find it anywhere. I have test data in my database. How do I use angular to display the data from my django restframework api? In other words, what code would I put in my angular controller and in my html file?

models.py

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class UserData(models.Model):
    """
    Requires a user id, email, first and last name.
    """
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name_first = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name_last = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from check import models as m
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = m.UserData
        fields = ('user_id', 'email', 'phone', 'name_first', 'name_last')
```

main urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', json_views.TestViewSet)

    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('^api/', include(router.urls, namespace='api')),
    ]
```

views.py

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = m.UserData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TestSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
```

I am assuming this is the basic idea, but I do not understand how to make the connection between the api data and the angular display.

app.js

```
testApp = angular.module('demoapp', []); 

testApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);

<body ng-app="demoapp">
<div ng-controller="testApp">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in data">
            [[user.user_id]] <br>
            [[user.email]]<br>
            [[user.phone]]<br>
            [[user.name_first]]<br>
            [[user.name_last]]<br>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

please look into below link and follow the tutorial you can easily understood how to use rest api with angular js.

1==http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/third-party-resources/
2== http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html

3== http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8frbgtj020